# Can i combine WCF and WebApi?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I want to host on the same website WebApi endpoints (RESTfull off course) and WCF endpoints (SOAP). I know it can be done if you do it all in WCF.

The question is - can i mix both technologies in the same website?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a WCF service and host with two endpoints.One for soap and one for REST.(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx)

Comment: I know but as i wrote in the question - i dont want to use WCF rest but rather WebApi Rest

Answer (score 2):

You can have both technologies under same website, provided there are in different virtual directory. For example you can place your api under "~/api" and your WCF service in "~/service". In such a case, both can co-exists.